# Unix script delete files after x days, but nog creation date

Tags: unix, synology

I want to create a unix script that deletes files after 5 days from our Synology. The follow script does this:

```
find /volume2/CHECKS -type f -mtime +5 -delete
```

But it looks at the creation date, not the date added to the shared folder. Is there an option to create a script that deletes files 5 days after adding to the folder?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `-atime` to work with date of last access, `-ctime` to work with date of last *status* change (file mode, etc), or -`mtime` to work with date of last file *content* change. The creation date is not explicitly kept in UNIX.

If a file is *not* changed after creation,  neither status nor content wise, both `-ctime`, and `-mtime` will server as *creation date*.